# Record camera live stream using MoviePy

Tags: python, python-3.x, video-streaming, moviepy

I'm trying to build an application where I need to show live camera streams to a user, as well as record those streams. I need to do it for multiple cameras (currently I'm starting with one only).

I'm able to achieve this requirement using `opencv` library, but I've been told by senior to use `opencv` only for live camera stream and use `moviepy` to record them. Now, I don't know how to how to handle the latter.

I looked for answers on google and stack overflow, but didn't find any. Please help if you know how to record using `moviepy`.

Below is the code using `opencv`:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:vaaan@123@192.168.1.51/Streaming/Channels/2")

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))


while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # output the frame
    out.write(frame)
    
    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('a'):
        break


cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have you looked at moviepy docs?

Comment: @itprorh66, yes but couldn't understand how to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with `moviepy`, the main reason being that `moviepy` is meant to process a video, see also why not to use `moviepy` in the section [do I need moviepy?](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/quick_presentation.html#do-i-need-moviepy). Stating not to use it when  `to turn a series of image files into a movie.` (which a stream basically is). I think the approach you have with `opencv` is much more efficient in handling the recording.